# Show the text around picture in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to add some informative text around the picture as showing in the picture below.

[image]

I am trying as to add it as;

```
function BS =  check()

size=8;
pixelBox=60;

board=imread('abcd.jpg');
board(1,:,:)=255;
board(:,1,:)=255;
oneBox = round(size*pixelBox/size);

counter=0;
for iter = 1:size
    board(oneBox+counter,:,:)=255;
    board(:,oneBox+counter,:)=255;
    counter= counter+pixelBox; 
end

% myBox=uicontrol('style','text');
% set(myBox,'String','Shani is not a boy');
% set(myBox,'Position',[30,250,50,50]);

imshow(board);

end
```

The problem I am facing is that, on commenting the text code that is

```
myBox=uicontrol('style','text');
set(myBox,'String','Shani is not a boy');
set(myBox,'Position',[30,250,50,50]);
```

The picture is showing with its complete dimensions. But when I add this text code, the picture resizes as

[image]

Why it is so? I want to show the text with complete dimensions of picture. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When another object is added into the figure, the existing axes/image/plot will shrink in order to make room for new object. This behavior is expected, and you can resize the picture with `set` command changing `Position`. Also see: https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/truesize.html

Comment: @Yvon Can you refer me to an example of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using `truesize` as

```
imshow(board);
truesize
```

Now it working as expected in complete dimensions.

Answer (score -1):

look for maltab function title(). You have to modify a little bit the way you show your image. Instead of use imshow, you have to do this way:

```
image = imread('foo.jpg');
figure, imshow(image), title('image foo');
```

with this three functions you can plot what you want. Look for title() function, i guess that you can change the title position. Something like this:

```
 ..., title('image foo', 'HorizontalAlignment', 'left');
```

Comment: Can we add multiple titles? Also, Can we add picture as a title?

Comment: This is going to add a title, which goes on *top* of the axes. `'HorizontalAlignment'` is the alignment of the text inside the box, not the alignment of the box.